# How to add retries to a loop upon failure?

Tags: python

1. My program accesses a website ex.) pastebin.com/SomeRandomData.txt
2. Sometimes the file may not exist, in which case it just catches the exception and moves on
3. My program has a minimum amount of data needed, so upon failure, that's a data point lost
4. Example) I need **20 files**; program failed to get **2** of those files and I am left with **18** **files** instead of the required **20**

**Question:** How do I add more retries to my program so that upon failure it will move on and attempt another file until it reaches those 20 required data points? (This is all in Python3)

Scenario: I am using a for loop and unfortunately I cannot just do this:

```
RequiredFiles = 20   

for _i in range(RequiredFiles)
 try:
  AccessSomeRandomWebsite()
 except Exception as e:
  RequiredFiles = RequiredFiles + 1
```

Comment: Forgot to add: I don't want to retry the link that's broken, that why I'd move on to the next data point link.

Comment: Is there a list of URLs you want to try to access and get at least 20 of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```py
urls = ... # you haven't specified how you get the URLs
results = set()
while len(results) < 20 and len(urls) > 0:
    try:
        result = FetchData(urls.pop())
        results.add(result)
    except:
        pass
```

This keeps going until you have 20 data points (or dont have more urls to try)

EDIT:

@alphaloop points out that if you run out of URLs before reaching 20 results, you have a problem. The code would exit the while-loop but `len(resuts)` are < 20 and you'd have to handle that :)

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a while loop. because you want your algorithm stop only when the condition is True
if AccessSomeRandomWebsite() function takes less than 1 minute then I suggest adding time sleep.

```
import time
RequiredFiles = 0   

while not RequiredFiles==20:
 try:
  AccessSomeRandomWebsite()
  RequiredFiles = RequiredFiles + 1
 except Exception as e:
  time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: `RequiredFiles` is an int. It doesn't have a `len`...

Comment: `RequiredFiles` is set to 20 initially and isn't updated. Also `len(RequiredFiles)` will throw an error as `RequiredFIles` in an `int`.